# ggplot2 barplot not adding correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been working with R for about 2 years now and I have no idea what is wrong here. I have this data frame that looks like this.

```
     incomeGroup    diabetic    percent
      (fctr)      (fctr)      (dbl)
1        <10,000 NonDiabetic 0.87689665
2        >75,000 NonDiabetic 0.93173965
3  10,000-15,000 NonDiabetic 0.80568579
4  15,000-20,000 NonDiabetic 0.84773930
5  20,000-25,000 NonDiabetic 0.83956823
6  25,000-35,000 NonDiabetic 0.86481373
7  35,000-50,000 NonDiabetic 0.86237913
8  50,000-75,000 NonDiabetic 0.91666293
9        <10,000    Diabetic 0.12310335
10       >75,000    Diabetic 0.06826035
11 10,000-15,000    Diabetic 0.19431421
12 15,000-20,000    Diabetic 0.15226070
13 20,000-25,000    Diabetic 0.16043177
14 25,000-35,000    Diabetic 0.13518627
15 35,000-50,000    Diabetic 0.13762087
16 50,000-75,000    Diabetic 0.08333707
```

I then use ggplot2 to make a graph using the following code:

```
ggplot(income3, aes(x = incomeGroup, y = percent, fill = diabetic)) + 
  geom_bar(data=subset(income3, diabetic == "NonDiabetic"), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data=subset(income3, diabetic == "Diabetic"), stat = "identity")
```

For some reason, the output is off. I get a graph that looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This makes no sense since I added up all of the numbers and they all equal 1. I don't know if this is a problem with ggplot or if I am doing something wrong. Below is code that will recreate the data that I am using.

```
incomeGroup <- c("<10,000", ">75,000", "10,000-15,000", "15,000-20,000", "20,000-25,000", "25,000-35,000", "35,000-50,000", "50,000-75,000", "<10,000", ">75,000", "10,000-15,000", "15,000-20,000", "20,000-25,000", "25,000-35,000", "35,000-50,000", "50,000-75,000")

incomeGroup <- factor(incomeGroup, levels = c("<10,000", "10,000-15,000", "15,000-20,000", "20,000-25,000", "25,000-35,000", "35,000-50,000", "50,000-75,000", ">75,000"))

diabetic <- c("NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "NonDiabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic", "Diabetic")

diabetic <- factor(diabetic)

percent <- c(0.87689664503343, 0.931739649923405, 0.805685791204679, 0.847739295548242, 0.839568230766604, 0.864813732451467, 0.862379127705366, 0.916662929943874, 0.12310335496657, 0.0682603500765948, 0.194314208795321, 0.152260704451758, 0.160431769233396, 0.135186267548533, 0.137620872294634, 0.0833370700561264)

df <- cbind.data.frame(incomeGroup, diabetic, percent)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by having two `geom_bar` calls, this leads to both bars being plotted on top of each other instead of stacked.
You don't need those and subsetting, try specifying the `group` argument instead:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = incomeGroup, y = percent, group = diabetic, fill = diabetic)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: You can also dodge the positions of the bars. @beetroot's way is more concise though.

Comment: Without the `group` argument, you also get the correct plot.